# allow special characters in get method route laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I've a url similar like this:

```
GET: http://test.com/testroute?title=#data
```

my route is:

```
Route::get('testroute', 'TestController@testFunction');
```

controller:

```
public function testFunction() {
    return Input::get('test');
}
```

When I trying the param

```
?title=data
```

ie, no special characters which returns the data. But with special characters which returns null.

I've searched on google and not found any better solution to solve this.
Kindly help me :)

Comment: try to wrap parameter value with quotes

Comment: tried this. But nothing happened

Comment: Try @OliveMaksimovic solution. It mast helps.

Comment: Let me try the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `urlencode()` the params passed via GET, otherwise they may not "work" just like in your case. `#` is one of the *delimiter* characters (`:/?#[]@`).

Comment: I've tried like this:
Encoded only the param.

ie, http://test.com/testroute?title=%23data (%23data instead of #data)